# An Inequality $\dfrac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}\geq (2n+1)\ x^{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> Show : 
>   $${\displaystyle \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}^* \quad \forall\ x \in [0,1]\cup (1,+\infty)\quad \dfrac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}\geq (2n+1)\ x^{n} }$$

My attempt:

Method 1:

Case $x=0$,
$$1\geq0$$
Then for 
$\forall\ x \in (0,1)\cup (1,+\infty):$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1 - x^{2n + 1}}{1 - x} &= 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{2n}\\
&= x^n \ (1 + x + 1/x + x^2 + 1/x^2 + x^3 + 1/x^3 + ... + x^n + 1/x^n)\\
& \ge (2n + 1)x^n
\end{align*}

since for $ x \in (0,1)\cup (1,+\infty):$ $$x + \dfrac 1 x \ge 1 + \dfrac 1 1 = 2$$
because of $$x+\frac{1}{x} \geq 2 \Longleftrightarrow  x^2+1\geq 2x  \Longleftrightarrow (x-1)^2 \geq 0$$

Methode 2

$$\dfrac{1-x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(1-x)}=\dfrac{1+x+x^2+...+x^{2n}}{2n+1}\geq\sqrt[2n+1]{1\times x\times x^2\times...\times x^{2n}}$$(Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means)

And the thing under the root is $x^{N}$ where $N=0+1+2+...+2n=\dfrac{2n(2n+1)}{2}=n(2n+1)$

- AM i right ?
- Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Did you not ask this question recently? Except fro $x=1$, that's right.

Comment: yes i did but i deleted

Comment: This is how awful a question looks like when you ask "what have you tried". Poor guy tormented by the closers hounds. Your question was perfectly formulated before and had good answers, which makes me think that it probably get un-deleted.

Comment: @  i deleted by myself while not satisfied totally with the comments guz i want to see if there is other ways to solve that problem